# UICollectionView does not load-iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UIViewController` which contains a `CollectionView` but as output goes all white

**In GridViewController.h**

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface GridViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource,
   UICollectionViewDelegate>{

  }
 @property (nonatomic, strong)UIImageView *imageHeader;
 @property (nonatomic, strong)UIButton * buttonHome;
 @property (nonatomic, strong)UILabel * labelTitle;
 @property (nonatomic, strong)UICollectionView * collectionView;

 //....
 @end
```

**In GridViewController.m**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    //....
     [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionView class] 
         forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

      NSLog(@"%@", self.collectionView);//here (null), why?
     self.collectionView.delegate=self;
     self.collectionView.dataSource=self;
    //...
  }

  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView
 {
      return 1;
 }

 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection: 
 (NSInteger)section;
{
     return 32;
 }



- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     NSString *kCellID = @"cellID";
     CollectionViewCellCustom *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageView.backgroundColor =[UIColor greenColor];


    return cell;
 }
```

Comment: Are you using xib? check the outlet is conncted

Comment: I do not have the IBOutlet, I did everything by code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not see any outlet in your code. So i'am assuming you are try to create it programmatically. For that you should do

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout= [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds collectionViewLayout:layout];
[self.view addSubView:self.collectionView];  
 [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]
        forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
 self.collectionView.delegate=self;
 self.collectionView.dataSource=self;
```

In your code i can see you doing `registerClass:[UICollectionView class]` which is wrong `registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]` is right.

Change

```
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionView class]forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

to

```
  [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

One more mistake you are using different cell id is for registering and dequeing. make it as same. Register the cell with id **Cell** and trying to deque using **cellID**

Comment: Now exit: *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:]

Comment: You are using different cell id's "Cell" and "cellId" make it as same

Comment: I corrected it, but now exit : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'

Comment: I think you are not creating layout object. see my answer above. you should create layout before creating collection view

Answer (score 1):

For sample code you can refere [this](http://yashesh87.wordpress.com/2012/09/12/uicollectionview-sample-code/).

Hope this will help you.

All the best !!!